# Changing UIImageView with scrolling the image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an NSMutbleArray with images. I puted the first image in UIIageView and then I want that the user navigate between images. Should I make button or there is other method? Can I do it when user touch the image, like photo on the ios?

I have another question please. Some time I see this kind of button, but when I select .xib , I don't find them?

[image: image1]

I have only basical button on object libraries

[image: image2]

help please ( and sorry about my english )

Answer (score 2):

Please watch the "Designing Apps with Scroll Views" talk from WWDC 2010.

Start [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/), log in, then look for that title, then click 'Watch in iTunes'.

Comment: thank you, i have a very slow internet it don't work and i'm newbie , it seem very hard . If i use button i will be able to make and animation ?

Comment: sure, but I don't think a scrolling set of photos is the first example you should do if you are brand new to programming, grab a book on intro to programming, and read it, then get an iOS book, then watch the videos. It is going to be very difficult for you (and your users) if you don't learn how to program before you start writing apps.

Answer (score 0):

Ummmmm, for a place to start:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

   UIButton *image = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

   [self setCurrentIndex:0];

   [image setImage:[array objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [image addTarget:self action:@selector(nextImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]

   [[self view] addSubview:image];
}

-(void)nextImage:(id)sender {
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

   [self setCurrentIndex:[self currentIndex] + 1];

   if([self currentIndex] >= [array count]) {
       [self setCurrentIndex:0];
   }

   [button setImage:[array objectAtIndex:[self currentIndex]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

You will need to keep a reference variable named `currentIndex` to keep track of where you are in the array and which image to display the next image. This is a pretty awkward way to do it, but probably the easiest to understand and fastest to code.

To answer your second question: Those buttons are for mac applications, not iPhone applications. You will not see them when you create a xib because the iPhone doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your second question first.  The little control next to the pop-up menu controls how the library items are displayed:

[image: Icon View]
[image: List View]

Regarding your first question, I suggest you use swipe gesture recognizers.  First, in your view controller, make actions for the swipe recognizers to send:

#### MyViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)showPriorImage;
- (IBAction)showNextImage;
```

#### MyViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)showPriorImage
{
    // You'll need to change this based on how you track the current image.
    if (self.currentImageIndex > 0)
        self.imageView.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:--self.currentImageIndex];
}

- (IBAction)showNextImage
{
    // You'll need to change this based on how you track the current image.
    if (self.currentImageIndex < self.images.count - 1)
        self.imageView.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:++self.currentImageIndex];
}
```

Then, in your XIB, find the swipe gesture recognizer in the library:

[image: Swipe Gesture Recognizer]

Drag a swipe gesture recognizer onto your image view.  In the Attributes Inspector, set the swipe direction to Left.  Then find the recognizer in the object list (on the left side of the XIB) and control-drag from it to File's Owner.  Choose `showPriorImage` from the pop-up.

Now drag another swipe gesture recognizer onto your image view.  Set its swipe direction to right, and connect it to the `showNextImage` action on your File's Owner.